# How to log error and return/continue a result/option

Tags: rust

I have come across many instances in that I need to write a code similar to this snippet. I was wondering if there's a shorter way to do it?

```rust
loop {
    let res = match do() {
        Ok(res) => res,
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
            continue;
        }
    }
        
    // Do stuff with `res` ...
}
```

or

```rust
fn some_fn() {
    let res = match do() {
        Some(res) => res,
        None => {
            eprintln!("Error: not found");
            return;
        }
    }
        
    // Do stuff with `res` ...
}
```

I was looking for something like the `?` keyword to return early with errors but in a case where the function returns nothing and I just want to return nothing if the result is `None`/`Error`.

Maybe something like this:

```rust
loop {
    do().unwrap_or_log(|e| eprintln("{}", e).continue // :D
}
```

And consider `do()` is never gonna be this short. It's probably a chain of a few function calls which is already too long.

Maybe the way I'm doing it is the only way or maybe I'm doing something wrong which makes to do this and I shouldn't be doing it!?

Comment: I'd probably write `match do(){ Err(e) => eprintln!("Error: {}", e), Ok(res) => { /* Do stuff */ }}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty much how it is. However nice the many chaining functions are, they cannot affect the control flow where they are used.

One suggestion I may make: if you have many fallible operations that need to be logged and `continue`d in an infallible context, you could move those into a single fallible function that you then can log and skip any errors all at once.

---

You aren't the only person to have complaints though and others have suggested changes to make this flow less bothersome.

There's the [`let else` proposal](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/3137-let-else.md), which I believe is implemented in the nightly compiler. It just needs to be documented and stabilized. It would look like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b07a0a86ad5b9499f14473df036bb036)):

```
let Ok(res) = do_this() else { continue };
```

Or perhaps a [postfix macro proposal](https://github.com/joshtriplett/rfcs/blob/simple-postfix-macros/text/2442-simple-postfix-macros.md) could be implemented eventually, which may look like this:

```
let res = do_this().unwrap_or!{ continue };
```

I'll note though that neither of these give access to the `Err(e)` value. So you'd still need a custom method for logging.

Comment: What about simply using a macro? After all, we don't need the postfix macro syntax to use them!

Comment: @BlackBeans you certainly could (I wouldn't though), I was simply providing suggestions that'd fit *"...a chain of a few function calls"* and *"something like `.continue`"*

Comment: Right! Incidentally, I found [this crate](https://crates.io/crates/postfix-macros) that actually allows you to use postfix macros.